# Connecting to RESTful site using Script Task

Tags: c#, https, ssis-2012

I have been trying various combinations of `HttpWebRequest` objects (in SSIS) to connect to webservices geocoding site to pull back individual geocoding information with no luck. This is a JSON response and `https` URL.

```
        string wUrl = "https://geocoding.geo.census.gov/geocoder/geographies/onelineaddress?address=1600+Pennsylvania+Ave+NW,+Washington,+DC,+20500&benchmark=Public_AR_Current&vintage=4&format=json";
        X509Certificate cert = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile("C:\\Users\\kwhauser\\geocode.cer");

        HttpWebRequest httpWReq = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
        //WebRequest httpWReq = WebRequest.Create(wUrl);
        //httpWReq.Method = "GET";
        httpWReq.ClientCertificates.Add(cert);
        //httpWReq.ContentType = "application/json";

        //ServicePointManager.ServerCertificateValidationCallback = (s, cert, chain, ssl) => true;
        //ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = true;
        ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls;

        //HttpWebResponse httpWResp = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        //HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWReq.GetResponse();
            //WebResponse response = httpWReq.GetResponse();
            //Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
                MessageBox.Show(" InnerException: " + ex.InnerException.Message);

        }
```

It doesn't matter if I try to load cert from file or use the callback one, I still get the same error message:

```
System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.
```

DotNet framework version is 4.7. The site expects TLS12. I've added simple REST Client extension to chrome and tested the URL with success. It fails on the `GetResponse`.

What am I missing?

Comment: Did you try using `ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;`? This will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = (System.Net.SecurityProtocolType)3072;
```

Comment: The only choices are `Tls` or `Ssl3`. There are no other choices. If I comment out the line and don't use it at all, same error message.

Comment: well thats unexpected.

Comment: is your SQL version SQL Server 2012 SP2 11.0.5644.2 or higher?

Comment: i can almost guarantee you need an update on your SSIS data tools/Server

Comment: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/3135244/tls-1-2-support-for-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: Install newer version (2.5.0.10728 or higher) and use System Default for SSLS/TLS if you have .net framework 4.5 or higher installed. This option is the easiest way to enable TLS 1.2 Support. 
If above is not working for you for some reason then try to select TLS 1.1 or Higher option from the Dropdown on the Advanced Tab. 

JSON Source, REST API Task, Web API Destination and XML Source all supports below setting on Advanced Tab

Comment: Thanks Michael!!  That was it!! Once I finally got SSDT updated it ran the first time.